# Correct way to return data from the database

Tags: java, sql-server, webdriver, odbc

I am new to Java and got stuck while accessing the data from database. I am using SQL server, WebDriver and Java. I created a class to connect to database and returning data to the caller. I am able to retrieve data from database in a two dimensional array ex- Object[][] dataset.

Caller class will get data like- Object[][] dataset. Sometimes my data has value of 0.00 (this is freight charge).

I am stuck while checking this value in the caller program as I want to check if freight charge is 0.

I tried following way but I am not sure if that's the correct way to do it. Can someone please show me the correct way to do it?

```java
private DecimalFormat freight= new DecimalFormat("#.##");


dbObj = new DBOperations();
dbObj.establishConnection("DSN_dbtest");
dbObj.executeQuery(queryFS);
resultSet= dbObj.getDataResult();

freightCharge =  resultSet[0][3].toString();

System.out.println("Freight charge=" + freightCharge); =>Displays .0000

if( freight.format(Double.parseDouble(freightCharge.toString())).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
            System.out.println("Freight charge is =" +freight.format(Double.parseDouble(freightCharge.toString())) );
```

Class - DBOperations-

```
package lampsplus.utilities;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Types;

public class DBOperations {

    private String connectionString=null, formattedString;
    private Connection  conn;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet resSet;
    private ResultSetMetaData rsMD;
    private Object[][] dataSet;
    int rows,cols;





    /**
     * This method returns a result set retrieved from the database.
     *
     * @return Object  - two dimensional array of fetched data. 
     */ 
    public Object[][] getDataResult()
    {
        return dataSet;
    }







    /**
     * Class constructor to initialize variables.
     *
     */ 
     public DBOperations()
     {
         System.out.println("initializing constructor dboperations:");
         connectionString="jdbc:odbc:";
         this.conn = null;
         this.stmt = null;
         this.resSet = null;
         this.dataSet=null;
     }


    /**
     * This method is used to create a database connection.
     *
     * @param string - dsn name to connect the db
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception - An unexpected exception
     */ 
     public void establishConnection(String dsnName) throws Exception
     {
         System.out.println("Establishing connection:");

         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         connectionString= connectionString+dsnName;
         System.out.println("connection string :" + connectionString);
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
         stmt=conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
     }


     /**
      * This method is used to execute a database query.
      *
      * @param string - Query to execute
      * @throws Exception - An unexpected exception
      */    
     public void executeQuery(String query) throws Exception
     {

         resSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
         rsMD= resSet.getMetaData();

         rows=cols=0;
         while(resSet.next())
             rows++;

         cols=rsMD.getColumnCount();
         dataSet= new Object[rows][cols];


         rows=0;
         resSet.beforeFirst();
         System.out.println("Data type ====" + resSet.getClass().getName());
         while(resSet.next())
         {   
              for(cols=0;cols<rsMD.getColumnCount(); cols++)
              {
                  if (rsMD.getColumnType(cols+1) == Types.NVARCHAR    )
                      dataSet[rows][cols]= resSet.getString(cols+1).toString();

                  else
                      dataSet[rows][cols] =(Object)resSet.getString(cols+1);


                  System.out.print(" " + dataSet[rows][cols]);
              }
              rows++;
         }   
     }


     /**
      * This method is used to close a database connection.
      *
      * @return void
      * @throws Exception - An unexpected exception
      */    
     public void closeConnection() throws Exception
     {
         System.out.println("closing connection:");
          connectionString=null;
          resSet.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
     }

}
```

Comment: `DBOperations` class, is that some API class or custom?

Comment: Well, I think that value in 'resultSet[0][3]' is a BigDecimal. Can you do the following and tell us what the output is: System.out.println("Class: " + resultSet[0][3].getClass().getName()); ?

Comment: @R4J - it says - java.lang.String

Comment: @Aninda - I created custom class DBOperations where I am creating connecting and executing query.

Comment: Show us this class then.

Comment: I have added it. Please take a look.